# Calculating following probabilities when $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Consider $X_1, ...,X_5 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{5} X_i$ and the variance given as $S^2 = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^{5} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$.
How can I then calculate the following three probabilities:

(1) $\mathbb{P}[\bar{X} - 2.059 S < \mu < \bar{X} + 2.059 S ]$

(2) $\mathbb{P}[0.65 S < \sigma < 2.37 S ]$

(3) $\mathbb{P}[\{ \bar{X} - 2.059 S < \mu < \bar{X} + 2.059 S \} \cap \{ 0.65 S < \sigma < 2.37 S \}]$

My ansatz for (1) is

(1) $\mathbb{P}[ - 2.059 < (\mu - \bar{X})/S < 2.059 ] = \Phi(2.059)- \Phi(-2.059) \approx  0.9605$,

since $(\mu - \bar{X})/S \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: That's not the variance; it's the estimate for the variance based on the sample. The variance of the distribution is unknown, and the variance of the sample would have $\frac15$ instead of $\frac14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preassuming that the $X_i$ are independent here:

- $\frac{4S^2}{\sigma^2}$ has [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $4$ degrees of freedom.
- $T=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{S}$ has a [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with $n-1=5-1=4$ degrees of freedom.
- $T^{2}$ has an [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) with parameters $1$ and $4$.

Moreover $\overline X$ and $S^2$ are independent so that the outcome in $(3)$ is actually the product of the outcomes in $(1)$ and $(2)$

Hint on $(1)$:

You can rewrite $P\left(\overline{X}-2.059S\leq\mu\leq\overline{X}-2.059S\right)=P\left(T^{2}\leq2.059^{2}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still have one question: $\mathbb{P}[0.65 S < \sigma < 2.37 S ] = \mathbb{P}[0.65  < \sigma / S < 2.37  ] = ...$. How can I get this into the form of $4 S^2 / \sigma^2$.

Comment: $$P\left(0.65S<\sigma<2.37S\right)=P\left(\frac{2}{2.37}<\frac{2S}{\sigma}<\frac{2}{0.65}\right)=P\left(\left(\frac{2}{2.37}\right)^{2}<\frac{4S^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}<\left(\frac{2}{0.65}\right)^{2}\right)$$